# Listing a ChoiceField in django as Button

Tags: python, django, web

Is there a way for me to change the way ChoiceFields are represented in django from a drop down list to something like buttons with each having a different choice ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just need to change the style, you can pass the css class as attribute. See the [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/widgets/#styling-widget-instances)

```
select_media = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(
    attrs={'class': 'btn btn-primary'}),
    choices=MEDIA_CHOICES)
```

[image]

[image]

If you need finer customization, you can override the default widget templates and put whatever html you want.See the [docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/widgets/#select). Below code is for Django 1.11

```
class CustomSelectWidget(forms.Select):
    template_name: 'yourapp/select.html'
    option_template_name =  'yourapp/select_option.html'

class CustomForm(forms.Form):
    MEDIA_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'DVD'),
        (2, 'VCD'),
        (3,'USB')
        )
    select_media = forms.ChoiceField(widget=CustomSelectWidget(
        attrs={'class': 'btn btn-primary'}),
        choices=MEDIA_CHOICES)
```

Comment: Is the 'yourapp/select_option.html' the place to put the template in? can i use jinja ? I just want to make sure.

Comment: So just to clear things up. what I'm trying to do is to list the choices and not make a drop down. Can I just use a for loop and make a list of choices in the template file ?

Comment: @Ammar Yassir, you can put your templates any where django can find, but yourapp/select_option.html is the location people expect to find it. YOu can use jinja

Comment: @Ammar Yassir, Negative for your second comment. You can take a look at the original template in django to understand how it is implemented. You can find it from 'django/forms/widgets/select_option.html' in your site_packages folder.