# How to set a style class to a choice field in a Django form

Tags: html, django, django-forms, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-select

I am trying to set a bootstrap-select class to my choice field. However, I am getting a 'TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs''.

```
class constraintListForm1(forms.Form):

    region = forms.ChoiceField(choices=REGION, required=True)   
    operator = forms.ChoiceField(choices=OPERATOR, required=True )

    class META:
        model = constraintListModel1  


        widgets = {
            'region': forms.ChoiceField(attrs={'class' : 'bootstrap-select'}),


            }
```

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45426122/466066

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
widgets = {
    'region': forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'bootstrap-select'})
    ),
}
```

Or just use `forms.Select()`:

```
widgets = {
    'region': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'bootstrap-select'}),
}
```

Comment: **David Yang**, glad to hear it. If the answer was helpful for you, please mark it as the right one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You set `Meta.widgets`, so you should set a widget instead of a field:

```
class Meta:
    model = constraintListModel1  
    widgets = {
        'region': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'bootstrap-select'}),
    }
```